# Random quote with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a "Random Quote Machine" challenge for freeCodeCamp and using codepen. For me the jQuery part it's been the hard part to solve. Mi code is working well except for two issues:

1. I can't set an initial greeting quote when the page finish loading
2. My tweet button is not working

**My JS file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Initial quote not working
  let initQuote = $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&callback=", function (data) {
      $(".message").html(data[0].content + " — " + data[0].title);
  });

  $.(".message").append(initQuote);

  // Get quote button working ok
  $(".btn-quote").on("click", function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON(
      "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&callback=",
      function(data) {
        $(".message").html(data[0].content + " — " + data[0].title);
      }
    );
  });

  // Stuck on tweet button, not working
  $(".btn-twitter").on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.open('https://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent( + ' --'))
  });
});
```

You can see my pen [here](https://codepen.io/fabricI0/pen/JLQdrj)

Any advice is welcome

Comment: _"My tweet button is not working"_ <- that's because it's all commented out

Comment: I commented out the not working parts on purpose, undone already to avoid confusions

Comment: Seems fine over here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/4y0rw7nt/. `initQuote` will be a [jQuery deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) so not something you'd want to use in `.append()`

Comment: Just call the function `initQuote();`

Comment: @SachiTekina but it's not a function :/

Comment: I tried .append()  because it seemed to be the right function when I was thinking how to get a initial quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the initial quote is an asynchronous call so the callback will run **after** the value is appended:

```
// This will run before your network request returns
`$.(".message").append(initQuote);`

// Then the network request will finish, and call this callback to set the content:
let initQuote = $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&callback=", function (data) {
    $(".message").html(data[0].content + " — " + data[0].title);
});
```

This is working AOK.

Your Twitter button is really close. You just needed to add the quote: `$(".message").text()`

```
  window.open('https://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent($(".message").text() + ' --'))
```

All together: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxywZm?editors=0010

Comment: All confusion is gone now due to the simplicity and eloquence of your explanation, you are a truly js jedy @sean, tym